# Ubuntu One for Windows Phone 7

Tags: ubuntu-one, phone, microsoft, windows-phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an Ubuntu One client for Windows Phone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116593/is-there-an-ubuntu-one-client-for-windows-phone)

Are there any plans to provide an Ubuntu One client for Windows Phone 7?

I realise that it's not the most popular mobile platform, but there are people (including me) who would find it useful.