# Is there an Ubuntu One client for Windows Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-phone

Great Job All! How about a client for Windows Phones since a client is working for Windows 7?
Keep up the great work.

Comment: Windows Phone 7.5 =/= Windows 7.

Comment: Upto this moment ubuntu one is not available for windows phone 7.

Comment: You should file this as a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone.

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu One client for Windows doesn't really bring us much closer to a client for the Windows Phone platform.  Our desktop client is written in Python (and shares most of its code with the Ubuntu version), while WP7 apps need to be written with [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) or Silverlight.

Also, the desktop client works in terms of synchronising all of your files locally, while on a mobile platform where storage is limited and bandwidth constrained, it is more useful to be able to browse all of your files and only download the ones you're interested in (which is how the Android files app works).

While we don't have immediate plans to release a WP7 native application, the API that the Android client uses to access the service is publicly documented if you're interested in developing an application yourself:

https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/cloud

You also have the option to use Ubuntu One's web interface to access your files.

Comment: You used to have a .net client which would have gotten you wp7 support very quickly and would have worked on linux, windows, mac, IOS and android. And yet you dropped it. Very very strange choice.

Comment: Which client are you talking about?  Also, as mentioned above the mobile and desktop clients perform different tasks, so would need different backend code even if they were written in the same language.  Furthermore, I think you are underestimating the amount of unique UI and platform integration code that goes into each target platform.

Comment: The original windows client was written in .net. Granted you would need a different UI's but android, IOS and WP7 could share a back end. And you can't tell me that the destop and mobile backends couldn't benefit from at least some code reuse.

Comment: And that other client was not complete: it was easier to directly port the Linux client to Windows than complete the independent one.  And as stated before, due to the different strategies on desktop vs. mobile (sync vs. browse+download), it isn't at all obvious that it would help with a WP7 app.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out [this app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/ubi/8f61c442-f0b2-440b-8299-3f86832d37b3), although it seems to only implement the filestorage API.